# optimizing the stored procedure with indexing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[IBS_fetchrequested]
   @tid integer = null,
   @Tbaroced dbo.TBarcode readonly
as 
begin
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   if (select COUNT(*) from  Khanger_tbl 
       where tid = @tid and requested = 1 and delivered = 0) > 0
   begin
      select 
         t.TBarcode, k.HBarcode as keyloc 
      from 
         Khanger_tbl k
      inner join 
         transaction_tbl t on k.transactid = t.transactID
      where 
         tid = @tid 
         and requested = 1 
         and delivered = 0  
         and t.Tbarcode not in (select carid from @Tbaroced) 
         and t.status = 3
    end
end
```

In my database I have around 2 lack records.. if I add an index on `tid` in the `Khanger_tbl` my stored procedure performance will increase? How can I increase these stored procedure performance? Any other technique?

Any help is appreciated!

If I add an index, how that will affect to my inserts and updates?
how i can optimze this?

Comment: The columns reffered to in `where` clause (tid, requested, delivered, status, barcode), which tables do they belong to?

Comment: tid,requested,delivered belongst to Khanger_tbl and status,barcode belongst to transaction_tbl

Comment: Why are you checking for existence of record in table before running the query?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you checking for existence of data before running the query?
Just run the query, If there is no data you'll get back an empty recordset.  The way you're doing it you are reading the data table twice.

... and, yes, if there's no indices, putting an index on `tid` will speed things up.  It will slow down inserts very slightly.

As to `data distribution`, for any particular column in the table, this has to do with how many records in the table have each of the values in that column. 
 for example, for a boolean coluimn like `requested`, if the data distribution in the table is such that only a small percentage of records have the `requested`value = `1`, then putting an index on `requested' will speed things up more.

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[IBS_fetchrequested]
 @tid integer = null,
 @Tbaroced dbo.TBarcode readonly
 as 
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

   Select t.TBarcode, k.HBarcode as keyloc 
   From   Khanger_tbl k
      Join transaction_tbl t 
         on t.transactid = k.transactID
   Where tid = @tid 
     and requested = 1 
     and delivered = 0  
     and t.Tbarcode not in 
            (select carid from @Tbaroced) 
     and t.status = 3
```

Comment: ok,,sir,,in this case i have to give index to both(tid and requested)

Comment: in my case small percentage of records have the deliverd=0 and tid..so i can give index on both?

Comment: from execution plan how i can understand this is increased performance ??

Comment: sir could you able to give one hint

Comment: sir i want to check Table scan cost??